# IIS is taking lot of time to deliver first javascript and image file

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7.5

We have a Content Management Application and when we did the testing using a load runner we saw very good performance (pages were rendered less than 2 seconds (most of them in milliseconds).

But now we are monitoring the application with various tools and we noticed that the first session of the user is taking a lot of time (like 50 seconds) and when we check the first javascript and the first image loads in about 20 to 30 seconds each. 
It is always the first javascript and first image (how small the file size is, I swapped the file order and see the same behavior)
I am not sure where to start the debugging. Any help where to start the debugging will be highly appricated.

Thanks

Comment: How large are the javascript and first image files? Can you show the timings your seeing from a client/bowser perspective e.g. Chrome's F12 tools Network tab?

Comment: Did you create any httphandlers that could set up initial state? If yes, try to debug there.

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from checking out fiddler2. [link to Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/). If you are using Internet Explorer there is a debugger you can reach by pressing F12. Go to the Network tab and watch the timings. Long lasting rows there can be subjects to investigation